# How use my htaccess for a subdirectory instead of root directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I've a htaccess that's working for something that's exist in root, like https://www.example.com but in this case i want to use this htaccess for a script that's copied to https://example.com/app

In this case we don't have www and also our scripts are copied to app directory.

My htaccess that's working in https://www.example.com exist in below of this paragraph:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Matching any of 3 domains without www, and no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9]+)/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)? index.php?p_post=$1&t=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) index.php?search=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*) index.php?tags=$1 [NC,L]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Please help me to changing this codes for something like https://example.com/app

Thanks!

Notice: This htaccess is right and usable to use in sub directories and the problem was from my php script, after debug everything worked good.

Answer (score 1):

create a new .htaccess file in subfolder and type

```
Options -Indexes
```

if don't want to index there content.

Comment: The index page loaded but It's not working for posts, categories, search and tags and i have 404 Not Found error, when i want to open a link like https://www.example.com/app/courses/1/open-source-programming

Comment: look like permission error can you please tell me which server and os your are using

Comment: os: Linux , WebServer: LiteSpeed Web Server

Comment: The problem was in my script and solved after debug and I used my htaccess that's exist on here. Thanks